# Simple textFileStream input all lines/records go to a single executor

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, streaming

I am using python with spark streaming and the idea is simple, make streaming monitor a specific directory, and once there is new txt file with some lines existing, it is being processed.

The thing is there will be very few lines in each of the txt files, but processing each line will take big time. So I want the lines being sent to different executors so they can be processed in parallel.  The problem is they are all sent to one executor (or two)...

The code looks like below:

```
lines = stream_context.textFileStream(monitor_dir).repartition(4)
lines.foreachRDD(process_stream)

def process_stream(time, rdd):
    print('rdd partitions: {}'.format(rdd.getNumPartitions()))
    rdd.map(lambda line: parse_each_line(line, other_params)).count()
```

I get 4 executors so I repartitioned as 4, and I am running it in real cluster with cluster mode, and when it's printed in the "process_stream" method, the rdd.getNumPartitions() == 4.

So not sure what the problem is, is it caused by "Input Split" size settings that sits in Hadoop file system under the hood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `.repartition(4)` each RDD will be processed by 4 different tasks. But there is no such a fine grained control from user side to force each task to be executed on a different executor.

I guess for testing you could set `spark.task.cpus` value to `spark.executor.cores` (forcing each task to grab all cpu cores assigned to an executor). But that's not something you want to do in a real project.

Comment: Thanks facha!  Yea tested with this way the lines were actually sent to different executors, it was just because I had so few lines (<10) before and they were all sent to 2.  After put 1000 lines for testing, I can see they were dispatched fairly even to executors.